# Relatvity of Promise

Tags: special-relativity

Suppose there are two observers moving at a speed c/2 w.r.t. each other. Now they won't agree on simultaneity of space separated events.

Now they decide to host a race between two racers, with common starting point but different ending points.
They bet on their racers, that whosoever wins will pay the other one.
Say for an observer A, both racers are tied and no one is liable to pay the other.

But for the second observer, one racer would have won, since the events won't be simultaneous w.r.t. him , so he will demand money.

So both are correct in holding their grounds in their respective frames.

Suppose on no payment being made by A, B shoots him and A dies.

Who will win in the court of law if killing for money is acceptable ? So even keeping a promise is relative.

Doesn't this put a limit on proper functioning of machines. Like in A's frame B has malfunctioned. So, isn't this kind of saying machines in general will give us the desired output only in a particular frame

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being shot by people who do not understand relativity.

Comment: `Who will win in the court of law` First things first, this makes the question very subjective - it is not about physics anymore, it is about laws that only a spacefaring civilization would probably have the need for. The culture of such a civilization would dictate the results. If however you assume that the behavior of people in this civilization is deterministic, with another load of assumptions we could maybe say the result will depend on with whom the judge and jury share a frame of reference.

Comment: I think what's more problematic is that B's bullets travel at > c/2.

Comment: A faculty in my department would respond to this question with a simple "Yes."

Comment: @KidElephant He can always stop his motion and come to A to shoot him.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I understand relativity. Please tell me one bit of the question that is wrong.

Comment: `if killing for money is acceptable` Each party could just kill everybody else in the jury + other party until they eventually win because there's no one left to keep the case going against them :D

Comment: The "people who do not understand relativity" are $A$ and $B$, I don't make any claim about you. But I really don't see a physics question being asked here - how should we know what some hypothetical court of law decides about the hypothetical outcome of a hypothetical space race?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Doesn't this put a limit on proper functioning of machines. Like in A's frame B has malfunctioned. So, isn't this kind of saying machines in general will give us the desired output only in a particular frame

Comment: I'm not following you at all. What machines are you talking about?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Say A and B are computers, then one computer(B) is not working properly in a frame(A).

Comment: Because he shoots A? What do you even mean by "not working properly"? *Define your terms*, I (and others, I suspect) cannot follow you when you make such logical leaps.

Comment: Why does B have to shoot A? Why can't he just sue A? Then you don't have to make up a new system of laws and you get both parties in court where you want them and nobody gets hurt

Comment: @ACuriousMind Let's say A and B are computers. They are designed to bet and kill if the other person doesn't honour it. They were manufactured by a company for this purpose. Now there is a human in A's frame, he sees that the B computer has malfunctioned. So, it kinds of put a limit on manufacturing computers, that you can't manufacture computers and expect them to work just fine in any other frame.

Comment: But if I were the judge, I would find both parties in contempt of court for having bet on a race whose winner could never have been accurately determined in the first place. And no, this says nothing about machines, this simply says don't expect a right answer to exist if you already know there isn't one

Comment: @Iota No, in A's frame, B appears to be functioning properly because we know that B observes things differently and we can determine what B should observe and thus that it is working.

Comment: @Iota: it put a limit on programming computers to do nonsense.  But GIGO is totally true before you invoke relativity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their race is ill-defined. You can't declare a winner if you can't agree on the ordering of events. If they failed to pick a reference frame for the race before starting it, then of course an argument over the winner may ensue. No laws of physics have been violated.

If you try and extend this to "malfunctioning machines", then yes, a machine that was not designed with special relativity taken into account (like the race was designed without SR) will give unexpected results. But again, no laws of physics will be broken.

As to shooting people... that's murder, whether the bullet left the gun before you pulled the trigger or after.

Comment: I now realise, it was a stupid question as if you make decisions on the basis of relative things, your decisions are bound to be relative. Its like two people deciding to do something when their unsynchronised clocks strike 12, their so called somethings are bound to differ as they were based on relative things